# Django Tutorial. Page not found

Tags: python, django

I already search for any answer which could help me before write this question, but I haven't found anything that helps.

The thing is that I follow the tutorial and I can't see the view that I created.

Now I'm going to share my code:

**project urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path 

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**polls urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(" ", views.index, name='index'),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/
]
```

**polls views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    HttpResponse("Welcome to de Polls Universe Index")
```

OK I ALREADY KNOW WHATS GOING ON:

I forgot the RETURN before de HttpResponse.

Comment: Have you tried removing the space from the index path?

Comment: Hi Erik! Thanks for your answer. I have done what you said about the space and this is the error that throws: The view polls.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Nice. We are making progress. Now you just need to add `return `  before `HttpResponse`. so that the response object is actually returned.

Comment: That's it Erik. Thanks for your time. I'm impresive with your reputation hahaha. I'm a beginner and this things happen.

Comment: Glad I could help. Will put this into an answer so you can make the answer as complete and you also can get some more reputation point ;-)

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I guess that I've make the answer as complete as you told me but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- The path for the index view contains a blank, which must be removed
- The view function must return a response object. Please add `return`  in front of the last line.